# getcwd: work with symbolic links

Tags: unix, posix

```
int
main(void)
{
    char *ptr;
    size_t size;
    if (chdir("/usr/spool/uucppublic") < 0)
        err_sys("chdir failed");
    ptr = path_alloc(&size);
    /* our own function */
    if (getcwd(ptr, size) == NULL)
        err_sys("getcwd failed");
    printf("cwd = %s\n", ptr);
    exit(0);
}

$ ./a.out
cwd = /var/spool/uucppublic
$ ls -l /usr/spool
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root 12 Jan 31 07:57 /usr/spool -> ../var/spool
```

> Note that chdir follows the symbolic link—as we expect it to, from
>   Figure 4.17 — but when it goes up the directory tree, getcwd has no
>   idea when it hits the /var/spool directory that it is pointed to by
>   the symbolic link /usr/spool. This is a characteristic of symbolic
>   links.

This all above is from book Advanced Unix Programming by Rago and Stevens.

First, `chdir` follows symblic links, but what does kernel store under current working directory of the process? Just `uucppublic`?

Second, what did the author want to state by saying

> getcwd has no idea when hits /var/spool

As I understand, `getcwd` should start reading inode of `..` in folder `uucppublic` to jump to directory `spool` with parent `var`, not `usr`.  That is why `getcwd` should not care whether there was a symbolic or not. Because `chdir` follows symbolic links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you got the idea, but you're parsing the English wrong.

> getcwd has no idea when it hits the /var/spool directory that it is pointed to by the symbolic link /usr/spool

"when it hits the /var/spool directory" is a modifier on the whole clause:

> getcwd has no idea that it is pointed to by the symbolic link /usr/spool

and in that sentence, the "it" is "the /var/spool directory". So read it like this:

> getcwd has no idea that the /var/spool directory is pointed to by the symbolic link /usr/spool

The snippet you pulled out:

> getcwd has no idea when hits /var/spool

is not a meaningful fragment because it keeps the modifying "when" clause but drops the more important "that" clause which is the object of "has no idea..."

As a side note, you are working from an old book, so you should be aware that things have changed a little. `getcwd` is a syscall now (in Linux at least) so the old algorithm (traverse `..` and search for matching inode numbers) is no longer used. The dedicated syscall gives the same result faster.

Comment: It was published in 2013, not that old :)